# progress bar stroke color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a progress that has a different stroke color depending on the percentage. now i wanted to have the whole progress bar stroke to have a stroke color different from the percentage.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfLwszbq/1/) i want the other 50% to be on red and the other is orange. i cant seem to find how can I add a color on it.

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="container1"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#container, #container1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#container > svg, #container1 > svg {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#container', {
    color: '#FCB03C',
    strokeWidth: 5,
    trailWidth: 1,
    duration: 1500,
    text: {
        value: '0'
    },
    step: function(state, bar) {
        bar.setText((bar.value() * 100).toFixed(0));
    }
});

circle.animate(.5);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0


var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#container1', {
    color: '#FCB03C',
    strokeWidth: 5,
    trailWidth: 1,
    duration: 1500,
    text: {
        value: '0'
    },
    step: function(state, bar) {
        bar.setText((bar.value() * 100).toFixed(0));
    }
});

circle.animate(.7);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
```

On the Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gfLwszbq/4/). it is posibble on the 2nd circle to have the blue an animation same as the orange one? rather than appearing in an instant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:-

```
var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#container', {
color: '#FCB03C',
strokeWidth: 5,
trailWidth: 1,    
text: {
    value: '0'
},
step: function(state, bar) {
    bar.setText((bar.value() * 100).toFixed(0));       
 }
});
 circle.animate(.5,function(){
  $('#container path:first-child').attr('stroke','#4679BD').attr('stroke-width',5);
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gfLwszbq/3/)

Comment: is it possible that before that orange stroke fills in the default stroke color is  displayed? rather than display after the orange stroke is animated

Comment: question in the progress bar 2 on your fiddle is it possible to appear the blue stroke with animation same as the orange?